# Python - Using * unpacking in object indexing

Tags: python, python-2.7

Can I use asterix (*) unpacking in object indexing?

Let's say, I have an object X, which is indexing using three objects:

```
X[ind1, ind2, ind3]
```

But ind2 and ind3 are really complex ones.
Hopefully, there is a function y, which takes simpler objects, producing the tuple of the complex ones:

```
def y(ind2_simple, ind3_simple):
    #stuff
    return (ind2, ind3)
```

And my question - is there any way to do something like this:

```
X[ind1, *y(ind2_simple, ind3_simple)]
```

Or something different, but still as simple?

Comment: `ind1, ind2, ind3` is just a tuple. Just do `X[(ind1,) + y(ind2_simple, ind3_simple)]`

Comment: Thanks, it's quite straight forward. I am wondering, if an asterix unpacking is just for functions and methods, or can I use it anywhere else?

Comment: No, at least not in Python 2. There were some changes made to unpacking in later versions, e.g. see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/

Comment: Related but not an answer, you can construct a `slice` object using star unpacking.  [Here's an example of that to implement `re.partition`](https://github.com/asottile/tokenize-rt/blob/50bf8471eab7c50aa909ad3ba1a1dd0558065ebc/tokenize_rt.py#L25)